# Targeting specific folders based on folders within Python

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, targeting

Hello users of stackoverflow,

I had a question on how to target specific folders when looking within a folder for example, look at the directory tree below:

```
--> MAIN FOLDER --> Subject 1 --> A_Folder --> files
                --> Subject 2 --> A_Folder --> files
                              --> B_Folder --> files
                --> Subject 3 --> A_Folder --> files
                              --> B_Folder --> files
```

So Subject 1 has only one subfolder, A_Folder, but Subject 2 and Subject 3 both have two sub folders, A_Folder and B_Folder.

My goal is I want to add the contents of Subject 2 and Subject 3's A_Folder and B_Folder, but ignore Subject 1's A_Folder.

Currently this is how I am targeting the folders...

```
A_files = []                                                                                                                                                               
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                                  
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                          
        if "A" in dirName:   
            A_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))                                                                                                                                                                     

B_files = []                                                                                                      
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                              
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                          
        if "B" in dirName:                                                                                    
            B_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I target only folders that contain both A_Folder and B_Folder within in them without targeting folder that only contain A_Folder

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search".

Code like this will walk through the directory structure, totally ignoring any `"Subject 1"` directory.

```
#UNTESTED
A_files = []                                                                                                                                                               
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                                  
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                          
        if "A" in dirName:   
            A_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
        if "B" in dirName:
            B_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
    if 'Subject 1' in subdirList:
        subdirList.remove('Subject 1')
```

Comment: Rob, thank you for your advise, I thought I might need to use an if statement but I am looking for a dynamic way to code this for thousands of folders.  Will something like this potentially work?

Comment: A_files = []                                                                                                                                                               
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Path):                                                                                                                  
    for filename in fileList:                                                                                                                          
        if "A"  && "B"in dirName:   
            A_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))

Comment: B_files.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))